# Advice for making friends when moving from the US to the UK?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, making-friends

I'm moving from the US to the UK for my husband's job and I'm from Oklahoma/Texas/Georgia.  So I'm from the part of the country that is loud, direct, and open about everything.  Thus, I am worried about whether I'll be offending people a lot.  What are some key points to keep me out of trouble?  And beyond that, how do married 30-somethings make friends?  I'll be just outside of Oxford, in Bicester.

Comment: Welcome to Interpersonal Skills! I invite you to take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about the site and its guidelines. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bicester is a town, so from a UK citizen to a US citizen I would highly recommend getting yourself down to your local pub quiz (most pubs have one) and you can be as loud and open as you like, they normally get quite loud and the atmosphere will be quite fitting. It's one of those places where you can go on your own (there will be one or two people at the bar with a pencil going along with the quiz on their own), have a nice pint and your accent alone would strike up a conversation with the locals.

Towns are really quite simple, they love something new and they love friendly people. I'm sure you can be both.

<sup>as a bonus, here's a [quick guide](http://internationalscholarshipguide.com/10-british-etiquette-customs-shouldnt-forget/) to some British etiquette.</sup>

Comment: Also, in a pub, don't talk politics or religion (but I know that is also a normal thing in the US). Good luck and happy moving.  You'll like it in Bicester, we (the rest of the UK) would consider that neck of the woods, quite posh.

Comment: It's still worth repeating.  I am a little worried someone will ask me to explain the US President and politics.  I mostly find all of that shocking and sad.  I guess the UK has it's own troubles, but I also see a lot of people helping each other in the news.  There's an idea of everyone "doing their bit" that is very appealing.  It sounds like communities work hard and value small contributions, as well as large ones.  That's really very encouraging.

Comment: People in their thirties here will be understandable and you can simply say "I don't follow politics." if you wish not to talk about it (we're a polite bunch and won't push anything further, if you don't want to), it's normally people around my age (18 - 25) who will openly talk politics in public.You'll notice in a smallish town such a Bicester, most people will care more about what's going on around them physically than they will around the country/world. or they just care on social media.

Comment: @MichelleWhalenKaiser - Noone in the UK will be surprised to hear that you find US politics shocking and sad. Most people in the UK expect everyone to find current US politics shocking. Sure, you can expect people to ask you about it, but probably because they're looking for a conversation topic, and the first thing we think about for the US currently is Trump. If you don't want to talk about it you can say "I know, shocking isn't it!" and move onto another topic. Weather is always a nice safe topic to talk about with Brits!

Comment: What about volunteer jobs?  I have plans to do some online classes, but I like the idea of getting out.

Comment: http://www.cherwell.gov.uk/volunteering